# Sending Email With Celery Using Django Default Email Backend

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to send confirmation email to my registered user using Django and Celery. I am using RabbitMQ as the Broker. Whenever I'm executing the code, the celery log shows it is receiving the task and executing successfully, But I am not receiving any emails.

tasks.py

```
from celery.task import Task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from config.celery import app
from config.settings import default


class SendConfirmationEmail(Task):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_name = kwargs.get('username')
        self.user_id = kwargs.get('id')
        self.user_hash = kwargs.get('hash')
        self.user_email = kwargs.get('email')

    def send_email(self):
        confirm_mail = loader.render_to_string('mail/confirmation.html',
                                           {'user': self.user_name, 'id': self.user_id,
                                            'hash': self.user_hash,
                                            'domain': default.SITE_URL})
        text_email = strip_tags(confirm_mail)
        send_mail(
            subject='Confirm Your E-mail',
            message=text_email,
            from_email='no-reply@mysite.com',
            recipient_list=[self.user_email],
            fail_silently=False,
            html_message=confirm_mail
        )

     def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.send_email()

app.register_task(SendConfirmationEmail())
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from apps.siteuser.models import User
from apps.siteuser.tasks import SendConfirmationEmail


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_employee_details(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        task = SendConfirmationEmail(username=instance.first_name, id=instance.id, hash=instance.hash,
                                 email=instance.email)
        task.delay()
```

settings for Email & Celery:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://username:password@localhost:5672/vhost'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailtrap.io'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = MY_USERNAME
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = MY_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
```

Celery log:

> [2018-05-09 11:50:41,191: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: apps.user.tasks.SendConfirmationEmail[e63c0f5f-7b81-4065-85c1-9ef87acc792a]
>   [2018-05-09 11:50:41,197: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task apps.user.tasks.SendConfirmationEmail[e63c0f5f-7b81-4065-85c1-9ef87acc792a] succeeded in 0.004487647999667388s: None

NOTE: I have sent mail without Celery and it was working fine. But The Problem started after trying with Celery.I am using Mailtrap for development purpose.

Comment: task = SendConfirmationEmail ()   ??  where is SendConfirmationEmail. send_email()  ??  or SendConfirmationEmail.run()

Comment: On the next line I'm running `task.delay()` which I think execute run method on the class.

Comment: I would do it with `shared_task` `from celery import shared_task`

Comment: why do u use a class-based approach? is not simpler to convert it to just `@task() def send_email(username, id, hash, email): ...`? and then run `send_email.delay(username, id, hash, email)` from your signal? 2) if this is a delayed task - why u have written a special `signal` for it? it does not affect on the performance, you can write it from view, before `.save()` method. Or you can send email in signal without `delaying` it. These are 2 alternatives, which u use one in one.

Comment: @Chiefir Actually the signal will perform some other task upon saving the instance. this was just a part of the code. I liked to use the Class Based approach but it did not work. using `@shared_task` decorator solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I generally call a celery task

**Task.py**

```
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def task1(*args,**kwargs):
    pass
```

**Caller.py**

```
from task import task1


task1.delay(a,b,c...)
```

Is celery discovery configured correctly?

Comment: That solved my problem !!! Thanks.

But can you point me any direction where I can find good resource for using the same with Class Based Approach?

Comment: Haven't used, so don't know. Sorry mate.

Comment: Task classes are instantiated once so your init will be fixed.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/tasks.html

Comment: A task is not instantiated for every request, but is registered in the task registry as a global instance.

This means that the __init__ constructor will only be called once per process, and that the task class is semantically closer to an Actor.

Comment: There is an excellent package to send emails through celery, 
https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-email/

Comment: I think the problem is not with the package. Celery has stopped supporting windows since 4.*. So it may not work with latest windows anyway. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html